# Vb.Net LINQ Replace pattern

Tags: vb.net, linq

1. I want to create a sort of Input Mask from Access. I want the user to input romanian phone numbers like 07XX XXX XXX. The thing is that it needs to be a string beacuse some phone numbers will start with a + sign, so number formats can't be applied (to my knowledge)
2. What i have tried:

```
Dim d As String = "---- --- ---"

For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(TelRe, "[\S+]")
    d = Strings.Replace(d, "-", m.Value, 1, 1)
Next

sender.text = d
```

3. What i need:
   What i would like to know, as i am trying to learn LINQ, is there a shorter, prettier LINQ function to use with that code?
   Thank you

Comment: If the aim is to have two groups of three digits at the end, you could remove all whitespace and then insert spaces in the correct places, like: `Dim r = Regex.Replace(telRe, "\s+", "")` `Dim s = r.Insert(r.Length - 3, " ").Insert(r.Length - 6, " ")`.

Comment: it sounds interesting, but the thing is, this is happening as you type, so the length of the string is variable. Also i want the "-" to appear or disappear like a sort of placeholder.